# Paypal recurring profile result after suspend and reactivate

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Paypal Recurring Account API

1.What Happen when we will suspend  the recurring Account after second recurring payment

and reactivate after third payment due time.
Will It start from third or fourth Recurring installment?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether it was suspended due to max failed payments, or if you manually suspended it.

If it becomes suspended because of failed payments it will tally up the missed payments and then you actually won't be able to reactivate it until you collect the outstanding balance.

If you manually suspended, then it would start fresh when you re-activated it and the next charge would be whenever that next period would end based on the original profile details.

Comment: SUppose I started a recurring profile on 1-jan-2014 and second due payment will be on 1-feb-2014 but I suspend it on 31-jan-2014 and again reactivate it on 15-feb-2014 then it would start from second due payment or deduct the third payment on time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would just pick up again on the 3rd month.

Comment: Thanks for help.But How second payment will deduct if it starts from third.

Comment: If you've suspended the profile then it's not going to charge them during that time.  If you want to receive the second payment then don't suspend the profile.

Comment: Can I use  the recurring profile for some interval to check .I have checked its details.It was minimum one day.I have to wait for check the result for minimum one day.Thanks for the above answers.That saved a lot of my time.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here..??

Comment: Means When I create a recurring Profile .Its minimum time is one day for transaction Then I have to wait for one day to next recurring profile transaction.